# Orbit image showing behind current one with transparent background

Tags: jquery, image, carousel, transparent, orbit

How do I prevent coffee.jpg from showing up behind payme.png? The result I get when first loading the webpage is both images, but after I cycle through them once the coffee.jpg is no longer seen behind.

This is the relative test.html

```
<div class="container">

    <div id="featured"> 
        <img src="these/payme.png" />      // has transparent background
        <img src="these/coffee.jpg" />     // shows up behind payme.png
    </div>

</div>
```

and orbit.css

```
.container {
    position: absolute; 
    top: 50%; 
    left: 50%;
    margin: -250px 0 0 -420px; 
}

#featured { 
    width: 850px;
    height: 425px;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0);
overflow: hidden; 
}

#featured>img,  

#featured>div,

#featured>a { display: none; }

div.orbit-wrapper {
    width: 1px;
    height: 1px;
    position: relative; 
}

div.orbit {
    width: 1px;
    height: 1px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden 
}

div.orbit>img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: none; 
}

div.orbit>a {
    border: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    line-height: 0; 
    display: none; 
}

.orbit>div {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 850px;
    height: 425px; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I experienced this problem previously with transparent images, and found 3 options:

- Just give your slides background color (many people appear to argue that this is the best/only option).
- Use the "graceful loading" method presented in the orbit docs: http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/orbit.php (which I just noticed is strangely not very well implemented there..).
- Try some of the more hacky solutions that get thrown around by the many others that seem to have this problem (google "orbit stacking images" etc.):
- https://github.com/zurb/foundation/issues/228#issuecomment-8174780
- https://github.com/zurb/foundation/issues/228#issuecomment-8250138
- https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/foundation-framework-/QeWXr6JBprE

Answer (score 0):

Edit the orbit-1.2.3.css file on the dollowing lines

Line: 11 to 15

```
#featured { 
    width: 940px;
    height: 450px;
    /*background: #000 url('orbit/loading.gif') no-repeat center center;*/
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Edit the jquery.orbit-1.2.3.js file on the following lines.

Line : 88 to 94 looks like this:

```
//Set initial front photo z-index and fades it in
slides.eq(activeSlide)
.css({"z-index" : 3})
.fadeIn(function() {
//brings in all other slides IF css declares a display: none
slides.css({"display":"block"})
});
```

change it to:

```
//Set initial front photo z-index and fades it in
slides.eq(activeSlide)
.css({"z-index" : 3})
.fadeIn(function() {
//brings in all other slides IF css declares a display: none
//slides.css({"display":"block"})
});
```

then go to line 305 and edit it to look like this:

```
.css({"z-index" : 1, "display" : "none"});
```

line 337 change it to this:

```
.css({"z-index" : 2, "display" : "none"});
```

line 343 to this:

```
.css({"opacity" : 0, "z-index" : 3 , "display" : "block"})
```

line 351 to this:

```
.css({"left": orbitWidth, "z-index" : 3, "display" : "block"})
```

line 357 to this:

```
.css({"left": -orbitWidth, "z-index" : 3, "display" : "block"})
```

line 366 to this:

```
.css({"top": orbitHeight, "z-index" : 3, "display" : "block"})
```

line 372 to this:

```
.css({"top": -orbitHeight, "z-index" : 3, "display" : "block"})
```

line 381 to this:

```
.css({"left": orbitWidth, "z-index" : 3, "display" : "block"})
```

line 390 to this:

```
.css({"left": -orbitWidth, "z-index" : 3, "display" : "block"})
```

Answer (score 0):

Having experienced the same issue I found the solution for me to be setting in orbit js additional css `left: 0px` on first slide.

```
setupFirstSlide: function () {
  ...
  .css({"z-index" : 3,"left":"0px"})
  ...
}
```

Then changing orbit CSS file to:

```
.orbit .orbit-slide {
    max-width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left:-910px;
 }
```

`-910` being the width of the holding div.

Works for me with transparent png's.